# website images won't show on github pages or netlify

Tags: javascript, image, api, github-pages, netlify

I am having trouble having my GitHub pages display my websites images that i fetched from TMDB api. When i go to elements in the console and select the image it shows up and also when i run it through live server it seems to run fine. I have tried checking the images source code spelling, but i don't think that's the issue. Can someone please help fix this issue.

netlify link: https://clever-noyce-88985a.netlify.app/

```
export function showsContainer(type, result) {
  type.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<div class="trending_list">
          <img class="trending_image" src="https:image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${result.poster_path}" alt="" />
          <div class="trending_info">
              <p>Name: ${result.name}</p>
              <p>Rating: ${result.vote_average}</p>
          </div>
      </div>`
  );
  modalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterbegin",
    `<div class="modal_content">
          <span class="exit_btn">&times;</span>
          <div class="modal_header">
              <p class="title">Name: ${result.name}</p>
              <p class="rating">Rating: ${result.vote_average}</p>
              </div>
          <p class="description">Description: ${result.overview}</p>
      </div>`
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `img` you should use back ticks ` no quotes " or '.

Templates work with back tics!

Try it like this:

```js
src=`https:image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${result.poster_path}`
```

But again I think the problem is not that!

You should fetch the image using the `poster_path` that you get when you fetch the movies.

I assume you first fetch the movies:

```js
  const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${api_key}&query=${movieName}&language=en-US&include_adult=false`
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    setMovies(data.results);
```

Then you should **fetch** the `url` using the `poster_path` of the movie you want,  like:

```js
const ListItem = ({ movie }) => {
...
 const response = await fetch(
`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/${movie.poster_path}`
);
      
      setUrl(response.url);

....
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have to wrap your src attribute of the img element in double or single quotes.

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: Why would omitting those quotes (which are usually optional) cause 404 errors?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.